# Why cannot directly assign this value to variable?

Tags: c#

Below is a simple code, I declare a variable `startingMileage`, and assign it a value in a method.

However I get the following error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int startingMileage;
    //I get the error if I directly assign value like this: 
    //int startingMileage = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

    double reimburseRate = 0.39; //here I can directly assign value to variable

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        startingMileage = (int)numericUpDown1.Value; // assign the value inside method is ok
    }
}
```

My question is: Why I cannot directly assign that value to it?

Comment: Because in a `class`, it is a `field`, not a local variable. Read: [10.4 Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645750(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: And what did the error say?

Comment: @chris it says: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Comment: @SonerGönül you mean numericUpDown1.Value is a field? why it cannot be assigned to a variable outside a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error message says, numericUpDown1.Value is property of a non-static field (numericUpDown1) of the Form class, it has not a value at the point that the assignment executed but 0.39 is a constant and it can be assigned to the field at any time.

Besides, if compiler let you compile that code, you'll get a runtime exception because UI controls (e.g. numbericUpDown1) are instantiated in Form Constructor (InitializeComponent method) which is executed after field initialition of the Form class.

If you merge the designer code, it will look like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    NumbericUpDown numericUpDown1;
    int startingMileage = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    double reimburseRate = 0.39;
    ..
    ..
```

Comment: Plus, you want to record that value when the button is clicked, not when the window (Form) was created.